# search for words in excel and highlight them in C#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, highlight

i need to search for few words in excel and highlight those. Have kept the words in an xml file. Below is the code am using. The range takes even null which is taking more time and it reads the whole line(in string) instead of reading each word in excel. Pls help

```
for (int i = 1; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
    {
    XmlAttributeCollection xmlattrc = xmlnode[i].Attributes;
    object text = xmlnode[i].FirstChild.InnerText;
    string str;
    int rCnt = 0;
    int cCnt = 0;
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;
    Excel.Range range;
    xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)doc1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    range = xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A1","A10");

    for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
        for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
            {
            str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2; //am getting the whole row but i need to read each word seperately
            if (str == text.ToString())
                {
                range.Font.Bold = 1;
                range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This method finds the text and highlight the word in excel

```
public void FindTextAndChangeColor(string text, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentFind = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range firstFind = null;

        // Find the first occurrence of the passed-in text

        currentFind = excelWorkSheet.Cells.Find(text, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
            false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        while (currentFind != null)
        {
            // Keep track of the first range we find

            if (firstFind == null)
            {
                firstFind = currentFind;
            }
            else if (currentFind.get_Address(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value) ==
                firstFind.get_Address(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value))
            {
                // We didn't move to a new range so we're done

                break;
            }

            // We know our text is in first cell of this range, so we need to narrow down its position

            string searchResult = currentFind.get_Range("A1").Value2.ToString();
            int startPos = searchResult.IndexOf(text);

            // Set the text in the cell to bold

            currentFind.get_Range("A1").Characters[startPos + 1, text.Length].Font.Color = Color.Red;

            // Move to the next find

            currentFind = excelWorkSheet.Cells.FindNext(currentFind);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to that all the letters in the cell are highlighted. I think you want to highlight only the text in cell you searched. You can follow this

```
Excel.Range val = xlWorkSheet.Cells[18, "C"] as Excel.Range;
string match = "find";
string match2 = val.Value2.ToString();
int index=-1;
//Here apply  string  matching to find index of first letter of matching sub string 
// if the index is not -1  then do following      
        val.get_Characters(index, match.Length).Font.Color =System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
```